# Why these integrals modified from integral representation of Bessel function are zero?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, bessel-functions

The Bessel function $J_n(x)$ has the following integral representation:
$$
J_n(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(x\sin\tau-n\tau)}d\tau
$$
Here $x$ is a complex number and $n$ is an integer.

I am now wondering results of the following integral
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(x\sin m\tau-n\tau)}d\tau 
$$
with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I have calculated this integral numerically by `mathematica` and the results are: 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
&n=1&n=2&n=3&n=4&n=5&n=6&n=7\\
\hline
m=1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
m=2&J_0(x)&J_1(x)&J_2(x)&J_3(x)&J_4(x)&J_5(x)&J_6(x)\\
m=3&J_0(x)&0&J_1(x)&0&J_2(x)&0&J_3(x)\\
m=4&J_0(x)&0&0&J_1(x)&0&0&J_2(x)\\
m=5&J_0(x)&0&0&0&J_1(x)&0&0\\
m=6&J_0(x)&0&0&0&0&J_1(x)&0\\
m=7&J_0(x)&0&0&0&0&0&J_1(x)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The calculation detail is provided [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmfVF.png).

It seems that, for $n>=1$, $\forall$ $m$ with $n\%m\neq0$, this integral is zero.

I want to know the proof of the above observations.

PS: It is obvious that when $n\%m=0$, this integral can be reduced to $m=1$. I am just wondering why other entries are zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties) (switching summation/integration is valid because $\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|J_k(x)|$ converges)
$$e^{ix\sin t}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}J_k(x)e^{ikt}\implies\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(x\sin m\tau)-n\tau}\,d\tau=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}J_k(x)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(mk-n)\tau}\,d\tau.$$
If $m\not\mid n$ then $mk-n\neq 0$ for all $k$, and thus all integrals on the RHS are zero.

Comment: This expansion is very useful. Thank you! 
By the way, do you happen to know the expansion coefficient of $e^{i x e^{i t}}$ by $e^{ikt}$？

Comment: There's nothing special to know, it is $(ix)^k/k![k\geqslant 0]$ ;)

Comment: That is great! But for $k<0$? After all, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: For $k<0$ it is $0$. (I think we should stop chatting here.)